# How do physicists justify using $c^2$ in equations?

Tags: speed-of-light

Excuse my ignorance but I see physicists use $c^2$ in equations and I was wondering what reasoning they use to justify $c^2$ since, as far as I understand, $c^2$ must be an absurd quantity because there is a speed limit imposed by physicists themselves at $c$. If there is no motion faster than $c$, how do you justify using $c^2$ in an equation?

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE! You'll note that I have formatted your mathematical symbols using LaTeX style markup which is supported on the site with the MathJax engine.

Comment: Could you be more precise? What is wrong with $c^2$?

Comment: Note that while $c$ is a velocity, $c^2$ has units $m^2/s^2$ and is therefore not a velocity, so while of course the numerical value of $c^2$ measured in $m^2/s^2$ is much larger than the numerical value of $c$ measured in $m/s$, there is no violation of the "nothing can be faster than light" rule.

Comment: Even if it did have units of speed, that would be fine. Nobody said you can't have a number greater than c.

Comment: You would have to look at the context to determine if $c^2$ were absurd or not. More often than not, it serves to maintain consistent units. Context is the key. I just don't understand why people down-vote a question?? This kind of trolling is getting to be ridiculous. Added a +1.

Comment: Not that it's relevant to the question, but you *can* have a velocity greater than $c$, if you're a tachyon. If you are, you're not allowed to *slow down* to $c$, and the only direction you can travel in time is backward.

Comment: @AntillarMaximus - questions like this are too full of misconception to have any real use. -1.

Comment: @zephyr, personally I object more to the tone of it *"$c^2$ must be an absurd quantity ..."* when the poster has already professed ignorance on the matter. I don't think that's the way you get people to like you.

Comment: If the numerical value of c or its square concern you, I suggest you start utilizing more convenient units. Hint: the value of c is 1 lightsecond/second.

Comment: @zephyr, the OP started with "excuse my ignorance", what more do you want to see? Pushing an irrelevant answer down the chain is fine (by ++good_answers), but why shoot down someone's curiosity? I see no misconceptions. The guy is merely asking a question. It is for us to dispel misconceptions.

Comment: Yeah, there's nothing wrong with the way he asked the question. C^2 is a big number and he was thinking it was a physical quantity. It's a normal thing to try to relate math to real things. The answers below both point out that math doesn't always do this in a tangible way. This question should not be down voted.

Comment: @AntillarMaximus - to interpret c^2 as a velocity requires a fundamental lack of understanding of basic algebra. This is supposed to be a site about physics, not remedial math/science/logic. This question is nothing but useless clutter.

Comment: @AntillarMaximus - and as for tone, I agree completely with dmckee. The first few words do not excuse the rest.

Comment: @zephyr: This site is indeed about Physics and if I am not mistaken, the objective is to provide the best answer according to your interpretation of the question. It is a bit weird that you are expecting somebody to know the answer to the question they are asking. PS:Delivering an insult with a ":)" is still an insult.

Comment: @AntillarMaximus just because someone has a question, does not mean that question is about physics or suitable to this site. PS: way to miss the point.

Comment: If he had just asked the question, I wouldn't have downvoted. But he wrote this question as an implicit accusation that physicists are doing something stupid and absurd intentionally. My downvote was for the rudeness and trolling.

Comment: There is a [meta question](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/988/down-voting-questions-please-state-your-rationale) about this which would be a good place to post opinions about this - definitely preferable to holding a discussion in comments. (There is also [chat], of course) I'll probably be deleting the comments here after a couple days or so.

Comment: In units where  $c=1/2$, $c^2$ is less than $c$.

Comment: If the highest house number on my street is 4000, how can there be  a house on my street with 5000 square feet of living space?

Answer (score 10):

I don't think people should downvote this question so I will attempt a serious answer.

When scientists deal with physical quantities, they're concerned not just with the *number* but also what *units* the number is measured in. So the speed of light, $c$, is $299,792,458$ meters per second ($m/s$). Both parts, the number and the unit, are meaningful and important.

In particular, you do math on both the numbers and the units. So the speed of light squared is $$c^2=299,792,458\space m/s\times299,792,458\space m/s=89,875,517,873,681,764\space m^2/s^2$$

Look carefully at this answer. Sure, $8.99\times10^{16}$ seems like a pretty huge number based on normal everyday experience. But it really doesn't *mean* anything without the units. In this case the units are meters squared over seconds squared. This is not a unit of speed!

You have to compare apples to apples, or like units to like units. $c^2$ isn't faster - or slower - than $c$. It's just a different thing entirely; an orange.

As a matter of fact, it's not really valid to give it a physical meaning. What is it supposed to mean, square meters per square second? Square meters are area, but what area could this be? And what the heck is a square second? It's just not correct to think of $c^2$ as a really fast speed. Rather it is a mathematical constant that happens to have units of speed-squared.

So it's not a violation of the universal speed limit to use the speed of light squared in an equation.

As to why $c^2$ is used at all: it's basically an extension of the observation that the kinetic energy of a particle is $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$. Notice the units of speed squared there, as well. This is a simplification but should give you the idea.

Comment: [Wikipedia:Mass–energy equivalence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence) gives a pretty good description of the history behind the mysterious c squared.

Comment: Wow, very good synopsis. I knew somebody here could explain it ;-)

Answer (score 8):

By using $c^2$, physicists are not implying that anything is moving at that velocity because, as you said, c is the maximum velocity. Note, though, that $c^2$ is just a mathematical term.

A lot of the heavy math in physics doesn't relate to tangible things but rather to mathematical relationships. The example you're probably most familiar with is $E=mc^2$. This doesn't mean that matter moves at the speed of light squared or that it's moving at all. Rather Einstein's famous equation shows that a little bit of rest mass equates to a lot of energy. In atomic bombs, for instance, only a small amount of the bomb's payload is converted to energy but because the mass term is multiplied by the speed of light squared it ends up releasing a LOT of energy.

Someone else can probably provide a much more detailed explanation of where $c^2$ comes from, but I cannot. All I can give you is the above overview.

Answer (score 3):

*c<sup>2</sup>* does not represent velocity faster than *c* since *c<sup>2</sup>* does not represent velocity at all, just like *a<sup>2</sup>* does not represent length (*a* denoting the length of a side of a square here). You can see this easily checking the units: *c* is expressed in m/s while *c<sup>2</sup>* is expressed in m<sup>2</sup>/s<sup>2</sup>.